# Why does free() keep triggering a breakpoint

Tags: c, breakpoints, free

Can someone please tell me why my free() function keeps triggering a breakpoint? I then get a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library error: Debug Assertion failed! Program: ... .exe, File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp ... Expression: _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(block).

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")


int main()
{

IP_ADAPTER_INFO *pAdapterInfo = malloc(sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));

if (pAdapterInfo == NULL)
{
    return 1;
}

ULONG size = sizeof(*pAdapterInfo);
ULONG * pOutBufLen = &size;

if(GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, pOutBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) //When this error code is returned, the pOutBufLen parameter points to the required buffer size.
{
    pAdapterInfo = realloc(pAdapterInfo, *pOutBufLen);
}
else
{
    return 1;
}

if(GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, pOutBufLen) == NO_ERROR)
{
    while (pAdapterInfo->Next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", pAdapterInfo->Description);
        pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;
    }

}

free(pAdapterInfo);


getchar();

return 0;

}
```

SOLUTION: Ok, thanks for everyone for your responses. I fixed my problem with another pointer that I've called pAdapter:

```
int main()
{
IP_ADAPTER_INFO *pAdapterInfo = malloc(sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));
IP_ADAPTER_INFO *pAdapter = NULL; //for memory freeing purposes only
...

if(GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, pOutBufLen) == NO_ERROR)
{
    pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;
    while (pAdapter->Next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", pAdapter->Description);
        pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
    }

}

free(pAdapterInfo);
```

Comment: Most likely you have corrupted the heap. What is `size` intended to have the size of?

Comment: The while() loop is modifying the pAdapterInfo variable.  So free() can't work anymore.  You'll have to preserve the original value.

Comment: Additionally, you're modifying `pAdapterInfo`, it no longer points to the original block of memory that was freed, in that `while` loop. So if you get something back, and then move forward in that linked list, and then try to free the pointer, you will no longer try to free what you allocated. Instead, make sure you free the original pointer you allocated.